# How to set the height of a scrollable div as a percentage of the parent container

Tags: html, css

To make a `div` scrollable:

```
.scrollable-div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 49em;
}
```

How can I have `scrollable-div` adjust its height as a percentage of the parent container who's height is 100%?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: set a children height in percent? like `height: 49%; owerflow: hidden; owerflow-y: auto;`

Comment: 100% of what....please provide a [mcve]